# Would background check company also mark down HR bad reference when they request only for work duration and title?

Tags: background-check

I am in IT industry, I am now being background check by a company. I fulfilled my record in CV, and in the background check form align with the truth. However, there is one company in my working history, I have a bad relationship with colleagues there, and HR.

So when the background check company checking my information, would they also record this? Because I think when the company consult the HR about my work record, the HR high possible to mentioned my "bad thing". (The bad thing here doesn't means any criminal thing, but the office quarrel)

Of course, in the background check form, there is no place to ask me the reason I leave the company

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does an employer check as part of a background check](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14828/what-does-an-employer-check-as-part-of-a-background-check)

Comment: It would depend on the country, but in the US, if you only gave the name of the company, HR would only confirm your title and the dates of your employment, nothing else (in my state, they wouldn't even share the salary information). Just don't give the name of your former supervisor. If they ask for the names of every person you ever worked with, then you've got potential trouble, but I doubt that's the kind of background check they have in mind assuming you're just applying for a normal job.

Comment: What sort of background check is this? A security clearance background check, to determine if there are any factors that might make you a risk to government secrets? A working with children background check, to make sure you haven't committed any sexual crimes in the past to reduce the risk you might molest children?

Comment: If this question doesn't get closed as a duplicate, can someone please [edit] the title to reflect what the question is asking? I would do it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @shoover I updated the title, hope now would more clear

Answer (score -2):

HR will never give a bad reference. They will just state the dates you worked and maybe your job title. And unless a business owner had a personal issue with you they also are very unlikely to give a bad reference but you'd be wise to not give their contact info if you have any doubts.

Comment: There's no law stopping HR from giving a bad reference.  Its uncommon, but it does happen.  The reason they usually don't is CYA from liability, but some don't care.  There's also ways of giving a bad reference without giving a bad reference-  there's codewords they can use in giving their non-reference to show that the employee was a problem.  For example, mentioning they're not eligible for rehire.

Comment: @GabeSechan Well I've been in the tech industry for decades and, from my experience/observation, unless you had a personal beef with the owner it's not going to happen.

Comment: I remember a boss telling me they can tell just by asking "would you rehire them".  Anything other than a "yep absolutely" without hesitation and it would be treated as a bad reference.